# Powershell LastWriteTime is incorrect

Tags: windows, script, powershell, windows-server-2008, date-time

I am running the following script to create directories based on the first 9 characters in the filenames in the directory and then moving te files into these directories based on their filenames.

```
dir | %{ 
    $id = $_.Name.SubString(0,9); 
    if(-not (Test-Path $id)) {mkdir $id}; 
    mv $_ "$id\$_";}
```

Now, what I have found is that after running the script the folders are being marked with a LastWriteTime several years in the past.

Here is the output from Powershell

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        13/04/2006   7:25 PM            XXX095_00
d----        13/04/2006   7:29 PM            XXX285_0_
```

Can anyone tell me where this LastWriteTime is coming from?

Comment: Are you sure your PC's clock is set to the correct date and time? By default it should show you the current time and I can't think of any reason for it not doing so (unless explicitly overwritten).

Comment: get-date gives the current date and time.

Comment: Try disabling time stamps, reboot, enable, reboot and see if the root problem is NTFS http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/

Comment: Well I finally worked out where the historic times were coming from. All of these files were on a fibre attached storage array and the time was way off. Even though the OS had the correct time PS was taking the time from the.array. So all good now.

Answer (score 3):

Moving a file doesn't appear to count as a write. I guess that's because you aren't actually writing to the contents of the file. But you can update the LastWriteTime yourself. Try this:

```
dir | %{ 
    $id = $_.Name.SubString(0,9); 
    if(-not (Test-Path $id)) {mkdir $id};
    $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date;           # <---- Added line.
    mv $_ "$id\$_";}
```

(You don't need the semicolons, by the way, when your statements are on separate lines.)

Comment: Thanks for that dangph, this should resolve the issue, but I would have thought the OS would have taken care of this LastWriteTime. These folders all have last modified time in 2014 prior to the move.

Comment: @nate There are 3 types of "LastWriteTime"  There's `LocalLastWriteTime`, `RemoteLastWriteTime`, and `OriginalLastWriteTime`.  Those 3 live in the `Win32_OfflineFilesFileSysInfo` class.  As to which PS is using is anyone's guess (especially since the PS core module is compiled and lacks documentation).